# How to pass the query results to a MOD function in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-11-22 13:30:15')
```

--it will return the minute  (30)

MOD(30,5) -----I want to pass the query results (30) to this MOD function.

How can I achieve this?

I need a query to run.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking: are you looking for `mod(EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-11-22 13:30:15'), 5)` maybe?

Comment: see https://dbfiddle.uk/g_ZoV6ku

Comment: select mod (EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-11-22 13:30:15'), 5)  I tried this but its throwing error.

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/Sx1mdtj_

Comment: if you use postgresql 9.4 you must cast the extract result to integer like
``select mod (EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM TIMESTAMP '2011-11-22 13:30:15')::integer, 5)``

Comment: Are you really sure about version 9.4? That version is EOL since February 2020, almost 3 years. Start thinking about upgrading to at least version 14, maybe 15